# No wifi after upgrade to 15.04 , ethernet works fine

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.04

**Please find system log 
wifi worked fine in 14.04 LTS but not anymore after upgrade
many tx**

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 18 Oct 2015 18:31 CEST +0200

Booted last: 18 Oct 2015 17:59 CEST +0200

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.2.0-56-generic-pae #86-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 17:51:27 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Xubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ea] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:7008]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

43:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 [8086:4239] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN [8086:1311]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b163 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0007 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS451 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:231d Hewlett-Packard 4 GB Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

PRODID_1="RICOH
"
PRODID_2="Bay8Controller
"
PRODID_3=""
PRODID_4=""
MANFID=0000,0000
FUNCID=254

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 13652  0 
sparse_keymap          13658  1 hp_wmi
iwlwifi               366509  0 
mac80211              436493  1 iwlwifi
cfg80211              178877  2 mac80211,iwlwifi
wmi                    18744  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.16  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:a03f:4c1:4a00:<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3667 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2978 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2630515 (2.6 MB)  TX bytes:593407 (593.4 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:d4700000-d4720000 

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       851     1  0 17:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.5.1-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.12-3
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Auto Ethernet
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       1ccdca9b-790e-4d77-9260-9f5928d7cd28
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{4}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   1ccdca9b-790e-4d77-9260-9f5928d7cd28 | Auto Ethernet
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.1.16/24, gw = 192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1445189417
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       domain_name = home
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.16
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       ntp_servers = 195.13.1.153
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 2a02:a03f:4c1:4a00:<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/128, gw = fe80::6a15:90ff:fe11:de39
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         ip = fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64, gw = fe80::6a15:90ff:fe11:de39
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2a02:a03f:4c1:4a00::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

Sorry, try again.
[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Draadloos | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=Draadloos
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/PROXIMUS_FON]] (600 root)
[connection] id=PROXIMUS_FON | type=802-11-wireless | autoconnect=false
[802-11-wireless] ssid=PROXIMUS_FON | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Brussels (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (N/A), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-56-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
srcversion:     290AB40BBD26BABA465648D
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-56-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           queues_num:number of hw queues. (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality (int)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (int)
parm:           ucode_alternative:specify ucode alternative to use from ucode file (int)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           bt_ch_inhibition:Enable BT channel inhibition (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           plcp_check:Check plcp health (default: 1 [enabled]) (bool)
parm:           ack_check:Check ack health (default: 0 [disabled]) (bool)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           auto_agg:enable agg w/o check traffic load (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           no_sleep_autoadjust:don't automatically adjust sleep level according to maximum network latency (default: true) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-56-generic-pae/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     A2FF94B65BEDD5243E20746
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-56-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-56-generic-pae/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     8FC6FDEFE98BAF48701CC2A
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.2.0-56-generic-pae SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
ack_check: N
amsdu_size_8K: 1
antenna_coupling: 0
auto_agg: Y
bt_ch_inhibition: Y
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_restart: 1
led_mode: 0
no_sleep_autoadjust: Y
plcp_check: Y
power_level: 0
power_save: N
queues_num: 0
swcrypto: 0
ucode_alternative: 1
wd_disable: 0

[mac80211]
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:43:00.0 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   14.418898] systemd[1]: Found dependency on network-online.target/start
[   14.430893] systemd[1]: Found dependency on NetworkManager-wait-online.service/start
[   77.172720] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready (repeated 4 times)
[ 1738.252910] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx
[ 1738.253224] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 1771.245236] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:68:15:90:11:de:39:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 1771.245618] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:68:15:90:11:de:39:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:6a15:90ff:fe11:de39 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=76 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=130 CODE=0 
[ 1808.096817] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:68:15:90:11:de:39:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 1827.171210] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[ 1855.181723] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx
[ 1855.182048] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 1896.202442] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:68:15:90:11:de:39:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
[ 1896.202839] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=33:33:00:00:00:01:68:15:90:11:de:39:86:dd SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:6a15:90ff:fe11:de39 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=76 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=130 CODE=0 
[ 1928.047028] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:68:15:90:11:de:39:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: It is probably some unsupported upgrade. What did you upgrade to 15.04 and how?

Comment: I come from 14.04 LTS and selected in software&updates  tab updates the option to notify for any new version

Comment: That update procedure is all kinds of buggy.

Comment: 14.04 does not have kernel 3.2 and you can't directly upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04. It means that you upgraded another way.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong kernel for Ubuntu 15.04 for some reason.

You need to install the proper kernel by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

and reboot.

Comment: I tried this but no packages were installed/removed.

Comment: How about`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. I've heard rumors that `dist-upgrade` can be buggy sometimes too, especially  since you have an unstuble system it seems, so don't blame me if it gets screwed up more.

Comment: @RudyR Are you connected to internet?

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade and many files were installed now.
I am connected to internet via ethernet in the living room which is rather unpractical :)

Comment: You probably have wrong `/etc/apt/sources.list` with `precise` packages. Did you previously have 12.04? The easiest way will be to re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Many tx for your support .
I concluded my installation went wrong and beyond saving and reinstalled 14.04 LTS. All works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

The final one solution for this issue:

Open a terminal session and type `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.